# How to optimize select query with index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

I am not expert.
I have following query, which contains 10 tables
MainTable has 10 fields 1st Prime Key and rest foreign keys of 9 tables called TableE1 - 10.

The following query is making outer join in each table, i want to optimize this query with index.

I want to know, how can we optimize queries with index, this query is fetching 10 lacs (1 million) records in 36 seconds, how much time we can reduce ?

MainTable contains 10 lacs (1 million) records, TableE1-9 each table contains 5000 records

```
select M.RecID, 
M.E1, E1.Descr as E1_D, 
M.E2, E2.Descr as E2_D, 
M.E3, E3.Descr as E3_D, 
M.E4, E4.Descr as E4_D, 
M.E5, E5.Descr as E5_D, 
M.E6, E6.Descr as E6_D, 
M.E7, E7.Descr as E7_D, 
M.E8, E8.Descr as E8_D, 
M.E9, E9.Descr as E9_D
from ((((((((tableMain M  
    Left Outer Join TableE1 E1 ON (E1.RecID = M.E1) )
    Left Outer Join TableE2 E2 ON (E2.RecID = M.E2) )
    Left Outer Join TableE3 E3 ON (E3.RecID = M.E3) )
    Left Outer Join TableE4 E4 ON (E4.RecID = M.E4) )
    Left Outer Join TableE5 E5 ON (E5.RecID = M.E5) )
    Left Outer Join TableE6 E6 ON (E6.RecID = M.E6) )
    Left Outer Join TableE7 E7 ON (E7.RecID = M.E7) )
    Left Outer Join TableE8 E8 ON (E8.RecID = M.E8) )
    Left Outer Join TableE9 E9 ON (E9.RecID = M.E9)
Order by RecID
```

Comment: i want to show this in a datagridview in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes are probably not going to help this query very much, because the query has no filtering.  You are retrieving a million records.  How much of the time spent on the query is retrieving the values and how much is spent processing the query?

SQL Server has a good optimizer, that will use sophisticated join algorithms for doing joins.  It is quite possible that the query will run pretty well even with no indexes.

That said, an index on each of the "E" tables with both `RecId` and `Descr` could help the query:  `E1(RecId, Descr)`, `E2(RecID, Descr)`, and so on.  These are covering indexes.  For this query, SQL Server would use these indexes without having to read from the data pages .  An index only `RecId` would not work as well, because the `Descr` data would still need to be looked up on the data pages.

Note that these indexes would be unnecessary (redundant?) if `RecId` is already the primary key and `Descr` is the only column in the table.

EDIT:

This is too long for a comment (I think).

Here are some ideas for optimizing this query:

First, are all the rows necessary?  For instance, can you just add a `top 1000` to get what you need?  A lot of time is spent just passing the rows back to the application.  Consider putting them into a temporary table (`select into`).  That will probably run much faster.

Second, how much time is the `order by` taking?  Try running the query without the `order by` to see if that is dominating the time.

Third, how long are the `descr` fields?  If they are very long, even just a few thousand could be dominating the size of the data.  Note "very long" here means many kbytes, not a few hundred bytes.

Fourth, are the `descr` fields `varchar()` or `char()` (or `nvarchar()` versus `nchar()`).  `char()` and `nchar()` are very bad choices, because they occupy a lot of space in the result set.

Fifth (probably should be first), look at the execution plan.  You have present a pretty simple scenario so I have assumed that the execution plan is a scan of the first table with index lookups into each of the other.  If the plan doesn't look like this, then there may be opportunities for optimization.

EDIT II:

I will repeat. Transferring hundreds of megabytes from the server to an application will take time, and 30'ish seconds isn't unreasonable. (The return set has 10 ids = 40 bytes plus the description fields which are likely to be 100s of bytes per record.) The problem is the design of the layer between the database and the application, not the database performance.

Comment: yes RecID is prime key and descr is only field in the table, although should i make index with (recid, descr) ?

Comment: After creating index as you described, still taking same time

Comment: @HaiderAliWajihi . . . As I say in the answer, if those are the only fields in the table, then the indexes are not necessary.  The performance of your query is being driven by the amount of data being processed.

Comment: if i pick the result in temp table (into #tmpTab) it is taking 6 seconds

Comment: @HaiderAliWajihi . . . 6 seconds to run a complex query and save a million rows doesn't seem like bad performance.

Comment: but, when i use this query on my application than it takes 36 seconds to retrive full data in dataset, i need a way that reduce this time to fetch all records.

Comment: @HaiderAliWajihi . . . If you are transferring a million rows from the database into the application, then my first guess is that you have a poor application design.  You should be doing at least some of the processing in the database.

Comment: I got your point, but i am trying to search out that, to fetch 1 million records it is taking 36 seconds, is it right performance ? or we can enhance more the database to reduce the time.

Comment: @HaiderAliWajihi . . . I will repeat.  Transferring hundreds of megabytes from the server to an application will take time, and 30'ish seconds isn't unreasonable.  (The return set has 10 ids = 40 bytes plus the description fields.)  The problem is the design of the layer between the database and the application, not the database performance.

Comment: Thanx @Gordon Linoff now i am on the conclusion, can you edit your answer and add last comment in answer, so that i can mark it accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

If your tables `TableE1`-`TableE9` have lots of records, you need to create an index on `RecID` in all nine tables.
I guess you have many records and no indices currently, because 30 seconds is really slow for such a simple query.

Comment: i have clustered index on all primekeys, TableE1 - 9, in each table it contains 5000 records

Answer (score 0):

Lets give a try with following steps.

- Create a non clustered index on Main table with all the columns(E1 to E9).
- Create a non cluster index on each child table on RecID Column.

Let me know the comments/results.

Comment: i have clustered index on all primekeys, TableE1 - 9, in each table it contains 5000 records.
Is clustered index worthy ? or i have to make non-clustered index only

Comment: i create the index that you described, but it still taking same time

Comment: Ok. remove Non clustered indexes on child tables. Keep only 1st and and give a try.

Comment: same result, nothing changed

Comment: Keep main table result in temp table and Join all tables with that.

Comment: i am not understand, please elaborate more

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  pvt.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT z.RecID, /*z.ID1, z.ID2, z.ID3 ...,*/ z.FK_ID_Type, t.Descr
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  x.RecID, /*x.ID1, x.ID2, x.ID3 ...,*/ y.*
        FROM    dbo.MainTable x 
        CROSS APPLY 
        (
            SELECT  x.E1, CONVERT(TINYINT, 1) -- E1
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT  x.E2, CONVERT(TINYINT, 2) -- E2
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT  x.E3, CONVERT(TINYINT, 3) -- E4
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT  x.E4, CONVERT(TINYINT, 4) -- E4
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT  x.E5, CONVERT(TINYINT, 5) -- E5
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT  x.E6, CONVERT(TINYINT, 6) -- E6
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT  x.E7, CONVERT(TINYINT, 7) -- E7
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT  x.E8, CONVERT(TINYINT, 8) -- E8
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT  x.E9, CONVERT(TINYINT, 9) -- E9
        ) y (FK_ID, [FK_ID_Type])
    ) z INNER HASH JOIN -- or INNER MERGE JOIN
    (
        SELECT t1.RecID, t1.Descr, CONVERT(TINYINT, 1) FROM dbo.TableE1 t1
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT t2.RecID, t2.Descr, CONVERT(TINYINT, 2) FROM dbo.TableE2 t2
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT t3.RecID, t3.Descr, CONVERT(TINYINT, 3) FROM dbo.TableE3 t3
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT t4.RecID, t4.Descr, CONVERT(TINYINT, 4) FROM dbo.TableE4 t4
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t5.RecID, t5.Descr, CONVERT(TINYINT, 5) FROM dbo.TableE5 t5
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t6.RecID, t6.Descr, CONVERT(TINYINT, 6) FROM dbo.TableE6 t6
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t7.RecID, t7.Descr, CONVERT(TINYINT, 7) FROM dbo.TableE7 t7
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t8.RecID, t8.Descr, CONVERT(TINYINT, 8) FROM dbo.TableE8 t8
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t9.RecID, t9.Descr, CONVERT(TINYINT, 9) FROM dbo.TableE9 t9
    ) t(ID, Descr, [Type]) ON z.FK_ID = t.ID AND z.FK_ID_Type = t.[Type]
) v
PIVOT( MAX(v.Descr) FOR v.FK_ID_Type IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]) ) pvt;
```

Comment: thnx for reply, you may have spent time on writing this sql, i appreciat your response. But this sql sill taking 31 seconds now

Comment: What is duration for your solution ? Can you publish the actual execution plan for your solution and for my solution (using the XML format) ?

Comment: my query is taking 36 seconds

Comment: The execution plans (XML format) for both solutions could help.

Comment: the execution plan is too long, it can not attache here